# How can I turn an input into a list containing one character per letter?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to make a code breaker that can break codes.
I don't understand how to put the (n) letter of the code into a string and turn it back into a list and print it out into the terminal.

```
#This is python code
alphabet = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".split() #needs double alphabet as code will add up: w --> h, or the list will be out of range
while True:
    saves = []
    crack = ""
    totalSaves = []
    code = input("Enter code >")
    codeIndex = 0
    for i in range(26): #Length of alphabet
        for i in range(len(code)): #length of code
            #get the first letter of code into the saves code in here
            #use saves[codeIndex] if possible
            #I want the code breaker to be sort of like this: a --> c. At this case, I want codeIndex to be 2. If possible, I want to put the letters into saves[].
        crack = "".join(saves) #unsure about this use
        totalSaves.append(crack)
        saves = []
        crack = ""
    printIndex = 0
    for i in range(26):
        print(totalSaves[printIndex])
        totalSaves += 1
```

I'm sorry if you don't understand.

Comment: "one character per letter?", can you explain?

Comment: 1) You are changing the outer loop "i" within an inner loop (also "i").
2) It looks like you are just trying some kind of brute force to find, for example, a password. In that case, you might find combinatoric generators useful. Look at the Python manual page for `itertools.combinations()`. If you give it the letters you want to use and how many you want in each password, it will generate all the combinations for you, so you just need a loop to check if it works.

Comment: Note that `alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"*2)` will create your letter list.

Comment: Also note that, in most cases, you don't need to do the conversion.  Lists ans strings are both sequences, and behave nearly identically except for changing their contents.  `x[i]`, `len(x)`, and `for` loops all behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to break and combine the alphabets in the list, you can do like this.

```py
alphabet = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
alphabet_list = alphabet.split()
split_n = 5

result = []
for i in range(0, len(alphabet_list), split_n):
    result.append("".join(alphabet_list[i:i+split_n]))

print(result)
```

You will get output: `['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy', 'zabcd', 'efghi', 'jklmn', 'opqrs', 'tuvwx', 'yz']`